# how to restrict autocomplete choices in webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

i am trying out webstorm, and the autocomplete dropdown presents choices that are too verbose

for example:

[image]

how can I cut this down to a manageable level?  as it is, autocomplete is useless for api discovery.

Comment: Well ... see if turning off `Settings | JavaScript | Weaker type guess for completion` will do any better.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but yeah, i did that before taking the screenshot :P

Comment: Well ... try contacting JB support team directly then ( email to support@... ) -- usually they are doing very good job and should tell you what can be done here (or if this is a bug or something -- as long as you provide them good examples clearly stating what you expect to see and what you are getting instead).

Comment: Hi...did you get anything back from JB...because the autocomplete on WS is useless as it is...I'm surprised, they offer really effective tools both for java & c#.

Comment: nope, though if you use the EAP of webstorm 7 it's a bit nicer.  right now i'm using the VS 2013 RC for typescript coding, and webstorm 7 EAP for html+debugging

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by LazyOne, there is no *real* solution for this since JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. Webstorm tries to give you all possible options.

You might however, like to use Typescript, which essentially compiles to JS. The best option right now is to make a new topic on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Answer (score 1):

Try it with actual objects, preferably ones with JSDoc annotations. For ECMAScript/Node.js and similar basic stuff, Webstorm provides those annotations out of the box. In cases like that, auto-complete seems to work a lot better.